# Why does the script command not return the correct exit code when stdin is closed?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Simply put:

```
$ script -V
script from util-linux 2.23.2
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
$ false && echo This is correct.
$ script -qefc "false" && echo Also correct.
$ script -qefc "false" 0<&- && echo Why is this printed?
Why is this printed?
```

edit: added centos & script versions.

Comment: On what type of system are you running that? I can't reproduce what you're seeing on Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour